# Wordpress 404 on Subdomain

Tags: htaccess, 404-error, subdomains, apache

I have taken a copy of my Wordpress website and set up a subdomain, and virtual host (/var/www/subdomain/) on the existing websites server.
After moving the copy of the website I am getting a 404 error on all pages except the Home Page and WP Admin area.

Apache Conf file below;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.example.com
ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

*Edited*

Also below is the SSL Cert apache conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.example.com
ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain

SSLCertificateFile /certfile/directory/
SSLCertificateKeyFile /certfile/directory/
Include /certfile/directory/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have ensured the htaccess file is present, site url and home url are updated and resaved the permalinks, but the 404 error is still happening.
I have also tried disabling plugins to make sure nothing was clashing

HTACCESS File below;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The existing Wordpress website on the server (/var/www/html/) is working fine and has no errors.

Any suggestions on things I might have missed / not set up correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You've only posted `<VirtualHost *:80>` which just redirects to HTTPS (_aside:_ you don't need mod_rewrite for this), so you must also have `<VirtualHost *:443>` with a SSL cert that actually handles the request? Also bear in mind that WP stores the hostname in the DB, so it's not simply a case of moving the site files to a new host unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have included the conf files which handles ssl, my mistake forgot to include that one. Yes - I have updated the hostname within the DB, that was one of the things I initially did / checked after moving the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to have allowed `.htaccess` overrides in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container, so `.htaccess` is effectively disabled. Without `.htaccess` you'll naturally get 404s for anything other than the homepage if you are using "pretty" permalinks. (`.htaccess` is not required for requests to the homepage, since `index.php` is served by mod_dir which is no doubt configured elsewhere in the main server config.)

You need something like this inside the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container:

```
<Directory /var/www/subdomain>
    Require all granted

    # Enable .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

You don't appear to be allowing access (ie. `Require all granted`) in the config you've posted so you are presumably handling this outside of the vHost? But make sure you are not enabling access to too much.